# Difficulty in understanding login mechanism password security?

Tags: security, authentication, passwords

In our login page we enter username password and then submit the form. The password goes to the server where it is crypted using some algorithm and then saved to database. But when it is posted to the server it can be seen in firebug post data. So how is it secure i have seen the similiar implementation in other cases as well. Can not it be trapped in between the time it is taken from client to server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebug can see the password because it is acting as a proxy on your client (one of the two endpoints of the communications path). SSL/TLS (https) encrypts the data in transit between the two endpoints (think of it as a protected tunnel where the only way to see the real data inside is to be at one of the endpoints). Since Firebug runs on the client, it has access to the endpoint, where the data is not encrypted. Think of a tunnel you can pass data into that will be protected in transit; Firebug sits at the entrance to that tunnel so it can see everything that goes in (and comes out).

At a minimum, sending passwords (and any other sensitive data) should be done over SSL/TLS, to prevent someone/something not on an endpoint of the tunnel from seeing the data. Ideally, you will want to run everything over https to prevent session hijacking attacks (you can read all about that [in the Wikipedia summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking)). Any site not encrypting at least the exchange of credentials (passwords, etc) is not following industry best-practices and should be considered an insecure implementation.

Comment: Actually FireBug does not work as a proxy - SSL/TLS tunnels through proxies (since 1.1), a proxy cannot view the SSL data. Firebug can see the password since it is in the browser's process, i.e. it views the data *before* it gets encrypted by the SSL tunnel.

Comment: Different kind of proxy (or maybe a bad use of terminology). It's sitting in-line in the communications path that flows from the user to the server's application logic. While not a typical/formal HTTP proxy (based on SSL/TLS termination points, etc), it's functioning as one, and - from a user's point-of-view - it is one. I'll leave the semantics as another discussion. :)

Comment: So you mean all the site that run on http and are asking password for login are insecure??

Comment: What particular measures a http site can take other than going for https for making passwords more secure??

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. HTTP does not offer any confidentiality services, so any data sent over HTTP (not using SSL/TLS or another, equivalent, protocol that encrypts the data) should always be considered to be compromised. Any site that asks for a username/password, or any other sensitive data, and does not run over SSL/TLS should be considered insecure.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you are right. If data is sent in clear text to the server, it can be captured in Transit. Hence, always use HTTPS connection.

Comment: i am using https connection. Also if this is the case how can someone be sure on so many no https websites

Comment: the thumb rule is, Use HTTPS for sending confidential information like Credit Card Numbers, passwords etc.. For normal sites, it is not required. To answer your next question, maintaining a HTTPS is a costly affair. I found a link which will help you understand the same, before which you need to understand the concepts of Public-private key encryption, and the reason why Certification authority exists and the performance and cost issues in setting up the same.    http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070604161212AAsnSFX